# Trying to obtain images from another location but RedirectMatch in htaccess is ignored

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I've just setup a new subdomain 'preview', ie preview.example.com and I am setting up a replicate of the codebase of a live website (from the www. subdomain) so that I can have a duplicate environment for testing and showing my client recent changes.

I want to save myself having to copy over all the images to the preview and so the normal location under which images are saved in a WordPress site /wp-content/uploads/ is empty.    I wanted to ues a simple htaccess rule to get these instead from the live subdomain where the image at the same path will exist. In other words, a request for

```
https://preview.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/test.jpg
```

would be redirected to the following where the image exists..

```
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/test.jpg
```

I've tried to set this up with the simplest of htaccess redirect rules but it just seems to be ignored and I've no idea why.  Any idea how I can troubleshoot this?

```
RedirectMatch 301 /wp-content/uploads/(.*) http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/$1
```

Comment: Is `DocumentRoot` of `preview.example.com` same as that of `www.example.com`?

Comment: ...or where on the filesystem do these two hostnames point to? Whilst you can externally redirect the request, this is slow and doubles the number of requests hitting your server. What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file(s)?

Comment: @anubhava DocumentRoot is not set.  Is that an issue?

Comment: @MrWhite the two hostnames are on the same server yes.   Hardly anyone will be accessing this preview domain and it is password protected.   I would ideally make the change in the codebase to change the url spat out by each page but its quite a big complex site so really don't want to do that as it will mean changes in many places.

Comment: DocumentRoot is definitely set in Apache config for you. You can check `VirtualHost` config for `preview` subdomain

Comment: "the two hostnames are on the same server yes" - but where exactly on the filesystem? How do the two hosts relate to each other on the filesystem? Do you have access to the server config?

Comment: @anubhava I was looking in the htaccess.  So yes I've found the DocumentRoot, its definitely set to another distinct folder.  The two sites do not use the same folder.  They have totally separate folder structures on the server under /var/www/...

Comment: @MrWhite what do you want me to check, yes I have command line access.  As mentioned above, both are in seperate folder structures.

Comment: @AdamJones: If `DocumentRoot` folders are separate but on the same host then you can create a symbolic link of `wp-content/uploads/` and avoid doing any redirect.

Comment: @anubhava ah with you thanks! if you want to write an answer feel free ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

Scenario is that both subdomain and main domains are on same host but their `DocumentRoot` are set to different paths. OP wants to serve lot of images from subdomain but doesn't to do bulk copy.

Suggested approach without tinkering with `.htaccess` is to create a symbolic link of `wp-content/uploads/`. Only option suggested to use in .htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Which allows use of symbolic links for serving web requests.